# Yii2 - WebService API and Queue

Tags: php, yii2, queue, webservice-client

I'm using yiisoft/yii2-httpclient extension for consuming a web service.
i have a controller to create a new record in webservice.
for any reason the action create can be fail (timeout, ws is down, and others) it is correct put this action create inside a queue (like the yiisoft/yii2-queue) if the record fails, retry in the background?

controller.php

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUrl('http://******/rooms')
            ->setData([
                'name' => $model->name,
                'date' => $model->date,
            ])
            ->send();
        if ($response->isOk) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what the user should see. If the user needs immediate response, use a queue. But don‘t forget to tell the user the staus of the queue actions (ajax, seprrate controller action). And be aware of subsequent actions that depend on the queue actions results!